# Where should I define the DocumentClient when using ExpressJs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-dynamodb

I couldn't find an answer to something I wonder.

With Mysql in Expressjs, when I declared the MySQL connection in a post handling function, it would create a new connection every time my ExpressJs server got a request. Then, the server would throw an error, when the maximum number of connections were established between the processing server and the database server.

I was wondering if there is the same problem with DynamoDB.DocumentClient()? What is the best way of doing operations with DynamoDB?

Should I have the DocumentClient global as below, or is it okay if I leave it in the post/get functions?

```
...
// DocumentClient is out of the post function below
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

router.post('/loglogbaby', function(req, res){
    var params = { ... };

    docClient.get(params, function(err,data){...});

    req.json({response:"nonobaby"});
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Well it doesn't matter because DynamoDB works with **HTTP** requests in the back not with connections and pooling etc.. `DocumentClient` creates a HTTP request at the end. Its a library to make `low level api` easier. ([See here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.LowLevelAPI.html)).

So basically you create a programming level object every time you create it. Not new connections. And objects are cheap to create.

Answer (score 0):

Since AWS DynamoDB is already hosted service, there is no problem with where you create `DocumentClient` object.
Its good practice if you create a global object for it.

You can find [here](https://db-engines.com/en/system/Amazon+DynamoDB%3BMySQL) a comparison between MySQL and DyanmoDB.